# ADLS Get 2 REST API to list files in folder with SAS token

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am trying path API to get list of files in a ADLS Gen 2 folder. I have generated SAS for folder and able to access/download single file using the SAS. But when i try to list of all files in the folder I get 200(OK), but there is no data in response.

below is API  that i tried

https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/folder2/folder3=someid/folder4=someid/PartitionType=default?resource=filesystem&{sastoken}

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an **Azure ADLS Storage account** and created container:

[image]

Inside the Container I created 3 folders in the path **`https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/fold1/fold2/fold3`** and uploaded few files in each folder.

I generated the **SAS token** like below:

[image]

**To fetch the files in the folder, you can make use of below query in REST API:**

```json
https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/pool?directory=fold1/fold2/fold3/*&restype=container&comp=list&SASToken
```

[image]

The response will fetch all the files under **`fold1`**, **`fold2`** and **`fold3`**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks rukmini, when i try your API syntax it gives 400 The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server. Can you confirm if your storage account is  ADLS Gen2 (hierarchical namespace enabled)? SAS i have generated is using the user delegation. I am able to download individual file using the SAS but list API is not working.

Comment: Yes, I have created ADLS Gen2 Storage account and generated SAS token like above.

Comment: My scenario is SAS is generated at leaf folder (fold3 in your case). looks like you are using SAS generated at container level. can you kindly let me know how to use List API with SAS generated for folder level.